# Transliteration App in PHP

Tags: php, replace, translation

I am very new in php, infect this is my second script in php, it is a transliteration tool which transliterate word by word, It reads data from a txt file and then replace each word with new one. it works really good for small text but if the text is large it fails. Any help please.

```
<?php
$Urdu = array();
$Roman = array();
$str2replace = $_POST["S1"];
$Chr1 = array( "'", '"', "!", " ( ", " ) ", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", ",", ".", "/", "?", "<", ">", ";", "[", "]", "{", "}", "،", "۔" , "؟", "+", "-",  "=", "_");
$Chr2 = array( " ' ", ' " ', " ! ", " ( ", " ) ", " @ ", " # ", " $ ", " % ", " ^ ", " & ", " * ", " , ", " . ", " / ", " ? ", " < ", " > ", " ; ", " [ ", " ] ", " { ", " } ", " ، ", " ۔ " , " ؟ ", " + ", " - ",  " = ", " _ ");
$str2replace = " " . $str2replace . " ";
$str2replace = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $str2replace);
$str2replace = str_replace($Chr1 , $Chr2, $str2replace);
$file = fopen("Dict.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file)) {
$String = fgets($file);
$String = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $String);
$pos = strrpos($String, "/");
if ($pos === false) { 
// Not Found
} else {
$Urdu[] = " " . substr($String, 0,$pos) . " "  ; 
$Roman[] = " " . substr($String, $pos+1) . " " ; 
  }
}
fclose($file);
$str2replace = str_replace($Urdu, $Roman, $str2replace);
$str2replace = str_replace($Chr2 , $Chr1, $str2replace);
$str2replace = substr($str2replace, 1);
echo $str2replace;
?>
```

Comment: It takes too much time to convert and page crashed, i am looking for any idea to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. For starters why do you need to do str_replace 5 times?. This is the first thing to optimize.
2. Why don`t you store your dictionary as array and just include it, instead of reading it every time.

Comment: Dictionary is not completed yet, users are adding words

Comment: If dictionary is too big use DB to store it. MySQL might be overkill, but sqlite would work nice. I would also check Redis very fast stores data in memory.

Comment: its contains about eighty thousand words.

Comment: No surprise your application dies on bigger texts.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is how to handle this large text?

Comment: Start with properly setting up dictionary in DB (Any DB). Then after this works properly big text should not be an issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20477/discussion-between-user934820-and-e-p)